# Advantage to Old Users

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation

Isn't there an advantage for old users who started using SO much earlier?

There are many basic questions that have been asked and answered in an early time when SO was launched. These questions are accessed and seen even today thousands of times per day. So such users get a higher reputation than ones who recently joined.

However, most questions asked today are very specific and thus would garner very few votes (It's likely only few select people will find it useful). If today some basic questions are asked they would be closed immediately.

So it would take much longer for new users to achieve a higher reputation than established users who have answered or asked some basic questions.

Shouldn't the reputation process be normalized keeping in mind the above disparity?

Comment: @SList But an algorithm can be made to make atleast SO fair?

Comment: Who ever downvoted please give reason? The question is researched ( else how would I know about the trend), and its useful to new users

Comment: -1 will be because they answer "No" to "Shouldn't reputation process be normalized keeping in mind above disparity?". I know this is a dupe, can't find the target though..

Comment: Find target and than vote.

Comment: It's not *that* hard to hit the rep cap just from recently-asked questions. (Or to put it another way: if we restricted reputation to votes cast on answers given in the last month, I think I'd still hit it every day, so my old answers aren't an advantage in that respect. You could argue that I'm more likely to get votes than a new user, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: deceze gave a 100 times more answers in his time than Tejas Patel in his time. The rep is 200 times higher (answers also float around for a longer time, ...) so I would say it is quite okay. Even as a new contributor you can get roughly as much reputation from answered questions than in the old times. One could back this by statistics though.

Comment: "If today some basic questions are asked they would be closed immediately." That's because they've already been asked before, not because they're not useful. I don't think it would be in any way *fair* to penalize users who have been here for years and have contributed thousands of answers. (Just my totally biased opinion.)

Comment: *Year 2020: Q: Advantage to Old Old Users* - enjoy your advantage now, Patel ;)

Comment: How exactly is "normalisation" of rep points going to help anything? All it does is make *you* feel a little bit better at the expense of other people. Guess what? You have to *earn* them points, they are not just a right or allocation.

Comment: I think it's a bit like science. In the good old days, you became a science star for discovering that the earth revolves around the sun. Today, you have to be a lot more specific to make a dent...

Comment: @slugster: basically by melting old earnings. Trust is not forever. If you are not active now and not perform now as you did earlier the community's trust also should decrease in you. The community should know how can it trust you _now_ not how could it trust you 5 years before.

Comment: @tobias: No it's not. Although now seems to be easy to discover Kepler's and Newtons theorems, it was as hard in their time as 11th dimension string theory today. The same is not true for the question and answer: "How can I find a substring in language X". It was easy to answer at hist time. Now just the _question_ is credited with 25k

Comment: @g.pickardou *`If you are not active now and not perform now as you did earlier the community's trust also should decrease in you.`* Nope, you are fundamentally wrong there. The votes are a measure of trust in the answer as much as the author. An answer five years later is still as good for the question as it was when first tendered - it shouldn't lose trust because the author is less active. Anyway this is an old discussion which I have no intention of resurrecting and re-litigating all over again.

Answer (score 57):

Yes. Welcome to life. I ain't be getting anywhere in World of Warcraft either if I started now. Or get rich mining Bitcoins...

But SE isn't a competition. SE magic unicorn points do not make you rich, famous, money or get you the ladies. *"Hey ladies, I've got 200k interweb points on SO!"* ... Yeah, has never worked so far, sorry.
Except for Jon Skeet, for whom all of the above works.

**Reputation isn't a game for its own sake; it's a mechanism created to measure trust in you by the system. Older users are naturally more trusted to know and understand and properly take care of the system than new users. That's by design.**

You can still contribute to the community in a meaningful way by providing great content or improving existing content and by participating in the betterment of the community and the site on Meta. That'll eventually get you heard and make you feel good too. And may eventually culminate in a bunch of unitard points as well.

I would also say that more trivial questions are asked every day on SO than ever before. It's pretty easy to write decent answers (if you can, that is) to a bunch of trivial questions and gain upvotes (albeit that most of those questions should arguably be closed, but that's another topic). I still regularly hit my mortarboard on new questions I answered that day, not on old content. I think the chances of becoming a high rep user are as good as ever. It's just that others have a few years head start.

Comment: You're right that MUP don't necessarily give you fame and fortune... But sometimes you [get a cake](http://i.imgur.com/sYcFYqC.jpg) out of it :D

Comment: ROFL. I admit I got a t-shirt, a tossing game and a bunch of stickers out of it... ^_^;;

Comment: Wanna trade a slice of cake for a meta sticker?

Comment: If that's still the same cake @Lix, perhaps the OP might want to reconsider.

Comment: @Bart - tisk tisk tisk...jealousy makes you nasty :P In any case the cake has been perfectly preserved... I placed a historical lock on it.

Comment: @Lix Since you've hit your 10k a while back... I'll pass. ;)

Comment: Fine then.. More 10Kake for me! You're both officially un-invited from my 50K barbecue. :(

Comment: @Lix Even if I bring a 50Keg?

Comment: @deceze - ok ok ok... maybe I spoke too fast :P

Comment: You wrote: "..Older users are naturally more trusted .". If this would be true, we also can give points for years, what we obviously not doing,

Comment: the person who asked this question got like 4,000 reputation points: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-to-perform-an-if-then-in-an-sql-select?rq=1.  Clearly that shouldn't imply that they 'naturally [are] more trusted to know and understand and properly take care of the system'

Comment: " it's a mechanism created to measure trust" Absolutely, so why an user may get 20k from a stupid question while a current user need month or hard work for it?. Your answer has no point sorry.

Comment: @Adrian That's a bit hyperbolic. There are only a handful of questions where this ever happened, and even then it took *years*, sometimes close to a decade. Those suboptimal exceptions don't define the norm.

Comment: @deceze: They are not exceptions! There are already plenty of people complaining about that, we could just close eyes or try to improve. The point is, people with much harder work, quality and expressed knowledge are getting limited reputation compared to early trivial questions that 99% of newbies find helpful. SO has now relevance enough in the world to make this reputation valuable.

Comment: @Adrian Then feel free to suggest a way to remedy this and have the community throw their votes in on the issue.

Comment: @deceze: Already did, and there are several solutions around. The problem is, bankers are the owners of the banks: High-rep users are those who vote and use Meta. People like you are those who I need to convince, and who would lose from such a change.

Comment: @Adrian Well, no, in answer to your question it was pointed out that your suggestion would in fact create more problems; by a high rep user who agreed with your premise no less. Personally I'd also be on board with any solution. As long as it's a realistic solution which does *not* create additional problems.

Comment: @deceze: If you refer to this post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136059/revisiting-the-rep-cap-yes-again It would just need some tuning to get totally different results. Furthermore, the point is not to swap the user ranking, but to make a 2017 active user able to reach an user having been only active in 2009. It seem wrong to me that the first 300 users of the ranking have inactive users but only a couple newer than 5 years.

Comment: With all the respect, look at the following example: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5445/cms He has been unactive since 5 years (3.5 years active). Why not a single user with 3-6 years activity 5 times more posts can achieve his score?

Comment: @Adrian While I agree that that's weird, I don't see an inherent problem in it. If you're seeing this as a competition and you're trying to be the top user, you need to re-evaluate your priorities. I would agree that this is a problem if users can get semi-moderator status by essentially doing nothing *and then abusing that power.* Or if new users had absolutely no way to get moderating capabilities. That would certainly be against the idea and would need fixing.

Comment: @receze: Forget about me! Actually that is an answer valid for any issue in the world: Wars? bahh, just change your priorities and don't care about them.... No, this reputation mechanism has a purpose and a clear impact, if useless, then just remove reputation at all or limit it to 20k. If reputation has any meaning, then we need to do it as useful and correct as possible.

Comment: @Adrian Again, concrete suggestions are welcome. We won't be getting anywhere productive in these comments though. I don't have enough time or interest in the problem to solve it, but I'm open to evaluate suggestions if someone presents any. Become the champion of this cause and you may just move the needle.

Comment: @Lix how’s the barbecue planning going :P?

Answer (score -6):

From SO [What is Reputation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) *"Reputation is a rough measurement of how much the community trusts you"*.

According to this definition in my answer I am focusing on meaning of trust and not meaning of the word "reputation". I also try to explain how the current system is (re)creating the advantage, why it is not perfect for measuring trust level, why the time will make it worst, and also trying to explain why will it so hard change. (well, it will change, keep reading)

**Answer:**

Yes, there is an advantage and it will be very hard to change. However your question is a step toward that.

**Here is why:**

- Who wants melted her/his fortune?
- Who wants to really be challenged by newcomers, when it is possible to not to?

***Nobody***.

I simply do not understand why would be more trustable who asked 8 years ago "How to find a substring in X language?" (now with 25k) then did nothing for 7.999 years compared to someone who actively answering 100s of specific questions in the last 1 year? Can anyone who state that this is a working system, and needs no change?

It is possible to earn 100s points daily by doing nothing, not even logging in. I have only less than 4k, but I am also earning 5-10 daily just for my *old* existing questions.

One of the comments mention a person who has earned 2000 within 28 days. Surely she/he must work hard. Well, as a reward actually ***the difference his points and a person who has say 100k are increased***. The modest estimate for a 100k person earns 100 points per day by just doing nothing, so she/he earned 2800 (or more) same time, and her/his advantage increased by 800 points. compared to the month hard working member. **That's a problem**. (to be clear: I am not stating that the 100k person did nothing during that time.)

Easy to see that this effect described above is **strengthening itself**. That's also a problem. The advantages (the difference between points) will increase, the point numbers *diverge*. (instead of converge)  With other words: The time will not solve it as some comments state. You will *never* catch up those who have such a big advantage.

Some idea to a potential change:

Reputation, trust, karma is melting thing. You must earn it day by day. One good answer what you gave your fellow developer 10 years ago is not multiplied by 10000 value for today. It's not like as an IBM share. Instead it is forgotten.

Comment: Stack Overflow reputation is not a peer-reviewed mathematical model for tracking your actual *real world* reputation, and it's not supposed to be. It's *just a name* for what other sites call karma, or experience points, or clout, or a dozen other names. If you actually want rep, *go work at it*. [Here s a person](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6147506/nhouser9) who has been a member of the site for 28 days and has over 2000 reputation, gained by actually using the site, rather than complaining about it.

Comment: 1) Nobody complains for reputation, at least I was not. 2) About your arguments: Calling something to "reputation" then reject ideas what makes it closer to its real world meaning: it stinks a bit. 3: Regardless how we call it, all we agree it is related to trust level for a member. My arguments in the my answer are mainly related to this meaning (trust level) not the meaning of reputation.

Comment: To answering the interesting fact that there is a person who has earned 2000 within 28 days. Surely she/he must work hard. Well, as a reward actually the difference his points and a person who has say 100k are increased. The modest estimate for a 100k person earns 100 points per day by just doing _nothing_.so she/he earned 2800 (or more) same time, and her/his advantage increased by 800 points. compared to the month hard working member. That's a problem. (to be clear: I am not stating that the 100k person did nothing during that time.)

Comment: @g.pickardou your answer is not very readable and difficult to figure out what point you are trying to make with your **Edit** / **End Edit** through the answer.  If you are going to edit your answer to change/clarify your point, please just edit and don't leave the old content.  It will make your answers much clearer

Comment: OK, I just wanted to make clear my answers to the comment(s). But now I deleted all the edits

Comment: -10 wooo. On this question i notice that Insiders downvote outsiders which point a real problem :  old answers , same with low quality have many more points than recent answers with better quality. That doesn't mean that all insiders don't deserve their reputation but for some of them, we can not deny it is the case and so the reputation system seems having a bug.

Comment: I think you are 100% right, but exactly as you predicted, you got -13 from exactly those who own high rep.