# Users that live off of old questions

Tags: discussion, reputation, old-questions

Let's look at the top question on SO: [Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array)

The top answer was by [Mysticial](https://stackoverflow.com/users/922184/mysticial), who's a pretty high-rep user.

However, looking at his [reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/922184/mysticial?tab=reputation), he gets almost 100 rep a day from that one answer!

Is this a problem? Should there be some sort of reputation limiting on old questions? Or is it ok because it's well earned rep?

Comment: TAX !!! A tax I say !

Comment: If they're still getting rep, that means new people are coming across the answer and finding it incredibly useful. They deserve every point for having an answer that can stay alive for this long and still earn reputation. Every user should aspire to answer a question so well that it can stand the test of time.

Comment: I'm going to start putting cool looking photos in all my answers.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155862/shouldnt-rep-gains-from-old-questions-answers-eventually-stop-or-at-least-re

Comment: I'd like to just point out that reputation is already limited to 200 max per day (with the exception of bounties and accepted answers).

Comment: Does this mean that if we cut off Mystical's daily supply of rep crack, then he'll slowly (or quickly?) wither away and die?

Comment: @ThePhD You should post that as an answer. I aspire to vote for it. :-)

Comment: Does a handful of high-end users accruing buckets of rep for great (albeit old) answers harm the site? If not, then what is the issue. Should we be starting a "We are the stackoverflow 99%" movement to decry users that have large reps?

Comment: related (possibly a duplicate):  [Advantage to Old Users](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254964/839601)

Answer (score 6):

I guess the general consensus here is that reputation doesn't really matter, and that the users deserve the reputation. Past 20k (or 180k) rep you have all of the privileges anyway.

Comment: for the sake of precision, all of the privileges are currently achieved at _180K_ not at 20, see: [At what reputation does a user gain 100% maximum privileges?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136020/165773)

Comment: @gnat No; it's the 200k physical award (used to be a unicorn painting).