# Are reputation points working as intended?

Tags: discussion, reputation

UPDATE: This is an extremely rare situation AFAICT so please ignore

---

I hate that I look at my rep but that said I'm wondering if points are working as intended.

I ask because I saw at least a few questions and answers with +5000 upvotes. That means for one question or answer that person is eventually becomes a moderator on stackoverflow which hardly seems fair compared to someone that's answered say 400 questions. Of course I don't want to see people gaming questions and answers. Maybe there's no solution. Maybe those are the exceptions.

It just seems wrong that 1 question can make you a editor/moderator/etc and yet that's arguably not a good criteria for giving someone those permissions. They haven't in anyway proved through behavior they can be trusted to be good moderators. All they've done is pull a lotto ticket in happening to ask or answer 1 or 2 popular questions.

I'm not going to name names but for example there's a user that's only submitted 16 answers that has a 30k+ rep whereas there are other users who've submitted 200-400 answers and still only have < 10k rep. And they are not people gaming the system. They're people spending 15-120 mins to answer a question including writing working samples.

Was the intent of points that one lucky question or answer can make you a moderator of SO?

Thoughts?

Comment: There is a daily rep-cap. And posts don't get +5000 upvotes *instantly*, remember the site has been here for almost 6 years now.

Comment: There is a daily cap of 200 rep (excludes a few things like +15 for answers)

Comment: And those 'lucky' posts are **rare**! There are only 2 such questions, for example. 3 answers have reached that level. *Out of 13 **million** posts 5 have reached +5k!*.

Comment: Did those people do anything wrong with their powers? If not, just accept that when you are at the right moment at the right place, and do what you need to do, things might come easier to you than to others. You can call it luck if you wish.

Comment: Well, if I reached nearly 40k then it means something is broken indeed! Seriously now, first explain what you see as "working as intended" then we can discuss further. :)

Comment: I'm not sure why it matters whether the points came all at once or 200 a day. The point is someone who's only submitted a couple of handfuls of questions should arguably not be a mod. But under the current system that happens. If it's rare fine. But that still doesn't invalidate the point that people who contribute less get more responsibility whether it's a 3 XXXX point questions or 20 XXX point questions vs someone else with 400 XX point questions.

Comment: @gman: No, reputation isn't a perfect system, but it is working *well enough*. Really, I find your fear about someone reaching 20k with only one (or very few) posts *unfounded*. It just doesn't happen.

Comment: So, you know a user who reached 30k with only 16 answers? They must be *fantastic* answers, then, and yes, we have a few people here capable of that.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yes, [he's here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7473/laurie-young) and is arguably only a mod because of 2 good question. His answers don't add up to me to "should be granted moderator status". But checking another 120 high users I see this is probably a very rare exception so my bad for not checking how common this is before asking the question.

Comment: Related: [Diminishing returns / non-linear reputation from “great” answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201716) and [Life isn't fair](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202652)

Comment: "and still only have > 10k rep"  I think you mean to say that they still have < 10k rep.

Comment: If anything attracts attention it's a big banner saying "Nothing to see here, please move on" ...

Comment: see also: [Advantage to Old Users](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254964/advantage-to-old-users)

Comment: The **real** issue people are missing here in all the answers and comments is: Whenever a question/answer is the "first one" posted regarding a specific common problem, that question gets loaded with votes throughout the years, even the most simple ones So the advantage is really the first questions and answers. The more time goes by, the less common problems are reported that most users search for. I have seen many users with massive reputation that barely know how to spell in english, when I check their profile I see they have a couple of questions that got many upvotes throughout the years.

Comment: @user5890979 you are right, this is something I think they should consider reviewing. Just wait until a new language, IDE or library get released, get some time to use it and start answering questions to it. You'll "farm" reputation, and I think they should consider redesigning this situation.

Comment: Today, there [are 186](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A5000..) such posts.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Reputation points have never worked as intended. The core problem is that most of the reputation is gained from activities that are not in the slightest related to site moderation. Most notably, you can gain reputation from possessing in-depth technical knowledge. And you can gain it simply from being active in one of the mainstream tags that receives a lot of traffic.

None of the above is in the slightest related to how suitable you are for site moderation. The assumption that a technical expert is automatically a great moderator is incredibly flawed. It might very well be the other way around; just make an empirical experiment and look at the kind of people you encounter at any large technical company. In general, the kind of people working in the R&D department are going to be quite different than the ones working with customer support. The R&D people are brilliant at interacting with computers, but often far less so when it comes to interacting with humans. It's simply because technical jobs attract such introvert people.

So yes, someone can gain a lot of rep for one single brilliant post and it will unlikely make them suitable for moderation. But that doesn't mean that they are less suitable than the person who earned 50k+ rep simply because of their technical expertise. There's for example a lot of high rep users who are notably rude. They might get away with it because their knowledge is very valuable to the site, but they are definitely not moderator material.

On the other hand, you can do thousands of edits, edit reviews, close votes and other moderation tasks, without receiving a single rep point. You do get some badges here and there for doing moderator work, but those don't give you any moderator privileges.

As an example, I've personally just passed the 20k "end game" mark and gotten full moderation tool access, as far as it goes for users. All of it for persistently sharing technical knowledge over several years and none of it for doing thousands of reviews and other moderation tasks.

So yeah, the reputation point system is definitely not working as intended, but that's how it is. I find it unlikely that SO will ever make any radical changes to it.

Answer (score 15):

No one can reach 20k reputation *instantly*. You can only earn 200 points per day from upvotes; there is rep cap in place. That means that even if a post reached a 100 upvotes in a day you still only get 200 points, not 1000. In practice that means you need a lot more than just 2000 upvotes to get 20.000 points.

And no post has gained 5k upvotes *overnight* either; the site has been around for almost 6 years now, the posts you are referring to all have been around for a *significant amount of time*.

Last but not least, with over 20 million posts on the site (7.4 million questions, 12.9 million answers) **only 5 posts** ever reached 5k upvotes. Only 99 questions even reached 1000 upvotes. 211 answers made it that far. These kinds of scores **are rare**.

Lets single out [Mysticial](https://stackoverflow.com/users/922184/mysticial) as the most extreme example. This user wrote 3 of the 211 answers with over 1k votes. The highest voted answer ever came from this user. It took 3 months before Mysticial reached 20k, *all before any of the 1k+ score answers were written*; all answers from that period are fairly average in score. In other words, even Mysticial, the one user you could accuse of reaching 'moderator-hood' from a single answer, already reached that point before ever writing that answer.

Comment: It's irrelevant if the points come fast or slow. The point is people who contribute less get more responsibility whether it's a few XXXX point questions or 20 XXX point questions vs someone else with 400 XX point questions.

Comment: @gman: yet anyone with such an answer **has contributed**. Give me one user with 20k+ rep that has, in your eyes, not contributed. Really, there is *no problem* here.

Comment: You fail to see the point of the question. What does it matter if someone gained 5k rep overnight or over time (despite how active they are on SO during that time), for post one single brilliant question/answer? Neither will make them a good moderator.

Comment: @MartijnPieters [Here's your one user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7473/laurie-young). 16 answers. He's a mod because he asked 2 good question. But, checking the top 90 users and another 60 at the 50k level I see that this is fairly rare. Just my bad luck finding that one user first.

Comment: @Lundin: So [peppering the site with 11k low-scoring answers](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) (Gordon's answers average 1.21 votes) makes him the better moderator, right?

Comment: @gman: So? He was an early bird, got in a popular question at the start of the site. He's been around on the site for nearly 6 years, don't you think he'll know a thing or two about how the site operates by now?

Comment: @MartijnPieters how would we know? He hasn't contributed. That's the point

Comment: @gman: It took almost [4 and a half years](http://stackexchange.com/users/4836/laurie-young?tab=reputation) for that user to reach 20k. He's been active on Stack Overflow; asked questions from time to time. Do you have any evidence that that user is abusing their powers?

Comment: @gman: Again, these are **exceptions**. You appear to be outraged by the fact this is possible at all, but I fail to see a problem. Are you complaining that *you yourself* have to work hard to achieve this?