# Split reputation points into question and answer points

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687758/how-can-i-add-an-html-element-without-affecting-the-position-of-existing-content) and wondered how the OP had gained so many reputation points. And especially so many badges.

At first I thought that s/he probably was a back-end developer taking his/her first steps on the front-end path. But later when I looked up [his/her history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1011816/hoa), I saw that s/he had answered **one question only**, and that s/he gained the points as good as entirely off (one) question(s). Questions that I would characterize as absolute beginners questions, for a forum that pretends to be a forum of/for (manual) programmers. Even though at certain aspects of programming I would characterize myself as an absolute beginner as well.

Now, the suggestion of maximizing the gained points off one thread has been [discussed and turned down](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259887/are-reputation-points-working-as-intended). Which I think is a pity, because I think the OP of that question had a very strong argument. But that seemingly is a passed station, as we say in The Netherlands. At least for the time being.

I would, however, have another suggestion -- to create two main reputation points figures. One for questions asked and one for the answers given. Has that ever been considered, and if so, what was the rationale behind not creating it?

Because this, plus the second question I linked to, make me value rep. points very differently. They can actually be as good as completely non-indicative of one's knowledge.

I realize that one can also 'get rich' with one answer, but splitting the figure halves the chance that the reputation points are indeed completely non-indicative.

Comment: You never should have thought of rep as an indication of knowledge in the first place... Rep should be thought of as more "how much has this user contributed to the community?", whether through asking questions or answering them. I do think I understand your thought process though, and I'm curious about whether letting people see question/answer contributions separately would be a good idea...

Comment: So if someone only answers questions, they get half the rep overall, because they don't ask questions? And how would permissions work?

Comment: Everything could work as it does now, except for adding statistics splitting out different rep sources for those who are curious about such matters. It does not seem very useful to me, because someone can be an expert in one or more fields, and an interested novice in other fields.

Comment: That OP has 142 questions, including 20 questions that have earned a "notable question" badge. IMO (s)he is far from earning all their rep on just one question... That being said - it's an interesting idea. it might be interesting to see the Q/A rep split - even if rep is still gained cumulatively from both

Comment: @user3580294: my return question would be: how much has that user contributed to the community, in terms of helping out askers? Isn't that what should have the most weight?

Comment: @FrankConijn reputation is *already* more heavily waited to favor answerers vs askers.

Comment: @FrankConijn It depends on your point of view. One can argue that good questions help the community just as much as good answers, and the latter has a hard time surviving without the former. In addition, as Cupcake stated, answerers already have a rep "advantage" over askers, so you could say that helping out askers already has more weight. But you seem to want the weight of specific question/answer contributions to be *visible*, in which case I'm not certain what to say. I'll have to think some more...

Comment: @Cupcake: apparently, that is not so when it comes to badges.

Comment: @gunr2171: I'm new here, and I don't know yet about permissions, other than that they are related to the points level. But if someone only answers questions, they will get less points anyway. Whether or not the figure is split.

Comment: @FrankConijn Apparently, given the votes, the user has helped other askers by having already asked their questions, so that the answers are on-file.

Comment: Users who only answer don't get less points, I am one example(bad example I know) who has only answered till now and never asked any question, and I have some rep. A great example is [this week's highest rep user](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation) [Martijn Pieters](http://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters), he primarily answers and has asked only 2 questions, and he has good reputation points @FrankConijn

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: that may be so, but imo the OP has shown little or no research effort. Still, he is gaining points rapidly. With a split figure, you can much better recognize the 'knowledgeables'.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion: with a split figure, Martijn Pieters would stand out even more.

Answer (score 5):

Like you already figured out, you can quickly get an impression of whether somebody is a "question" or "answer" type of person, or a balanced mix, by opening their profile, and looking at how many questions/answers they have posted. Particularly if you sort them by votes, the picture normally becomes clear almost immediately.

If you hover over scores in the "Tags" section of the user profile, it also displays the scores for the tag separated by questions and answers.

Since at least a rough form of the data is quite easily accessible already, I'm not sure if displaying separate rep points adds a whole lot. I guess it could be kind of interesting if the number of rep points earned from questions and answers could be displayed in the profile, e.g. next to the corresponding question/answer counts. I would just look at it as additional statistics, without any consequence.

About the meaning and usefulness of rep numbers: To me, it's a number that might have some correlation with certain properties/qualities of the user, but it's definitely not a completely reliable predictor for anything. Whether it's knowledge or trustworthiness, it's definitely possible to get a high rep without having an extraordinary amount of either. But I'm convinced that any other quantity you define would have similar problems.

Realistically, somebody having a high rep makes it likely that they have at least been active on the site for an extended period of time. So if you have to define an objective measure of who you want to trust to e.g. cast votes, it seems like a reasonable starting point to trust the users who have spent enough time on the site to understand how it operates. I hope everybody realizes that it won't be a successful prediction 100% of the time, but there should definitely be a correlation.

There's a theory that as soon as you define a way to quantitatively evaluate people, they adjust their behavior to maximize their score, often in ways that defeat what you wanted to achieve when you defined the score. Say you want to maximize productivity of an organization, and define a measurable productivity score to evaluate people. Chances are that people will find ways to increase their productivity scores, but the organization will end up being less productive.

I think that at least to some degrees, rep numbers are an example that confirms this theory. But the same thing would happen no matter what measurement you use.

Answer (score 4):

### Reputation's purpose as a measurement of user trust

Reputation on Stack Overflow is primarily used for a very specific purpose: **it is used to measure how much the system can trust a user with additional privileges**, such as downvoting, close voting, deletion voting, bypassing the edit review queue, etc.

Given that, your suggestion for splitting up reputation between rep from questions vs answers **doesn't really improve the usefulness of reputation** for the Stack Exchange system. The platform doesn't really care *where* or *how* you earned your reputation, because higher reputations are approximately indicative that **a user understands how the Stack Exchange Q&A model works**, regardless of whether that reputation was earned from questions or answers.

### Reputation as a metric for other user qualities?

The usefulness of reputation as a metric for other user qualities, such as *domain knowledge*, is far more debatable, and **many veteran Stack Exchange users already understand this**. Reputation can easily be earned simply by asking popular beginner-level questions, or answering said questions.

So if you see a discrepancy between reputation and apparent domain knowledge and expertise, you must understand that reputation isn't really meant to measure these things...at least not any more (assuming that it ever was to begin with). As I've already pointed out, its primary purpose is merely to measure how much the Stack Exchange system can trust a user with additional privileges.

Comment: All the luck to him, don't get me wrong. But asking a couple of questions at beginners level that many other beginners apparently also have makes one a trusted user? Where's the logic in that? I mean, judging from your rep. figures, you could be someone who doesn't know left from right, but off one beginner's question could have earned your reputation, with the current system.

Comment: @FrankConijn as I've attempted to point out in my answer, deep domain expertise and knowledge aren't required to earn high rep. If anything, the only knowledge and expertise reflected by rep is knowledge and expertise in how the Stack Exchange system works. Of course, if someone has [ludicrously high levels of rep](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet), it's a stronger indicator of deep domain knowledge and expertise in a technical subject. A stronger indicator, *but not a guarantee*.

Comment: @FrankConijn and for the record, ***I do know*** the difference between left `=>` and right `<=`!!! `:P`

Comment: I've read your answer and know what you have pointed out. But that still doesn't justify the fact that a user can become a trusted user off in principle one question, without even having to have answered one question. That's just plain wrong! (And I know you from programming threads, so you I know that you know light from red. :-) But we shouldn't have to look up everyone's history, or have to know everyone 'in person'.)

Comment: @FrankConijn users have to earn 20k reputation to officially become ["trusted users"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user). With a daily rep cap of 200, someone would have to earn 40 upvotes on a single question for 100 days before they reached that level. Highly unlikely. Looking at it another way, a user could ask 20 questions per day, and have each question earn 10 upvotes, for 100 days. If someone manages to pull that off, then they clearly understand how to ask good, interesting questions, and thus they can be trusted to use additional privileges responsibly. In theory.

Comment: May all be true, and the OP in question has not yet reached the status of trusted user, but I strongly question the quality of his questions -- zero research effort, imo.