# Why this answer is grayed?

Tags: support

Sorry for the lame question. For a while [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322051/1157814) answer is grayed. It is neither flagged for close, neither deleted, but keeps displayed in gray.

I can not figure why...

Comment: Because it got more than 2 downvotes.