# Why does it seem all the upvotes on Stack Overflow are from 2008?

Tags: discussion

[Look at the posts in C# sorted by upvotes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23?sort=votes&pageSize=15)

The majority of the non-wiki posts are from 2008-2009, which doesn't make any sense. This is because more users should be accessing the site than before, and they overwhelmingly go to newer questions rather than older ones.

Like look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706500/how-do-i-generate-a-random-int-number-in-c) one.

> How do I generate a random number in C#?

If asked today, that would yield a billion downvotes and even more "oh you could have googled this." The thread from 2008? 1439 upvotes. How is this possible? Were people just more lenient in 2008? Did the Recession remove our hearts?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2706500/timeline

Comment: Just 10 years worth of Google hits, the top hit for "c# random number", 0.086% of the visitors marked it useful.

Comment: Also highly related: [Advantage to Old Users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254964/7795130) and its duplicate target.

Comment: I love when the first hit for a  basic question I have is a SO/SE link :)

Answer (score 14):

> Were people just more lenient in 2008?

Yes, very much so. When Stack Overflow first started, there were few guidelines as to what made a "good question" and the scope was very broad, with questions like cartoon requests and random things programmers were just interested in but didn't necessarily have anything to do with programming being *allowed*.

But as the community grew and matured, it also learned. It learned that the Q&A format offered here is not a good fit for certain types of questions. It learned what kinds of details need to be in a question in order to provide an accurate answer. It learned a lot of things about what it should and shouldn't do in order to ensure higher quality.

A lot of those lessons are passed on to new sites on the network, but pretty much every community suffers from this. Scopes are naturally more forgiving in the early days while a site learns about the kinds of questions it'll attract and what its scope needs to be.